# Python Unit Test: how to pass Exception (not raise) in unit test with mock?

Tags: python, unit-testing, sockets, pytest

I need to test this class in `client.py`:

```
import socket

class Client:
    def execute(self, url: str):
        try:
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            sock.connect(('localhost', 9999))
            sock.send(url.encode())
            data = sock.recv(1024)
            sock.close()
            print(f"{url}: {data.decode('utf-8')}")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error sending request to", url, ":", str(e))
```

In `tests` I have mocked `socket.socket` and trying to mock `sock.connect` so that it will return Exception:

```
import client

    def test_1(self, mocker, capsys):
        mock_socket = mocker.patch("socket.socket")
        mock_socket.return_value.connect.return_value = ConnectionRefusedError
        client1 = client.Client()
        client1.execute("https://example.com")
        captured = capsys.readouterr()
        assert captured.out == "Error sending request to https://example.com : [WinError 10061]"
```

But this Exception didn't triggered and I got this result in `captured.out`:
`"https://example.com: <MagicMock name='socket().recv().decode()' id='1874290459152'>\n"` 
instead of
`'Error sending request to https://example.com : [WinError 10061]'`
which shows that I didn't hit `except Exception as e:` block.
How to pass this Exception properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a mocked function raise an exception when called, set the [`side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) attribute instead:

```
mock_socket.return_value.connect.side_effect = ConnectionRefusedError('[WinError 10061]')
```